# Does rapid decay of Fourier coefficients imply smoothness?

Tags: fourier-analysis

Under the isomorphism of Hilbert spaces $L^2(S^1)\to\ell^2(\mathbb Z),\quad e^{2\pi i n t}\mapsto e_n$, smooth functions on the circle are mapped to rapidly decaying sequences (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Properties)).

Is the converse also true? That is, does every rapidly decaying sequence in $\ell^2(\mathbb Z)$ represent a smooth function?

Motivation: For certain arguments, it would be really nice to read off smoothness from the Fourier coefficients.

Comment: When you say a sequence $c_n$ is rapidly decaying, do you mean it is $O(n^{-k})$ for all $k$ ?

Comment: @TCL: Yes, I do.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes. Smoothness is equivalent to the Fourier coefficients forming a sequence that decays rapidly (faster than any polynomial). To see the direction you asked about, note that if $\{c_n\}$ is a rapidly decaying sequence, then the sum $\sum c_n e^{in x}$ will converge uniformly as will every derivative. So the sum will represent a  smooth function. (The continuous analog of this is that the Fourier transform induces an isomorphism of the [Schwartz space](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Schwartz_space) onto itself.)

In general, one can use the Fourier coefficients to give an $L^2$ definition of differentiability. Morally, a function ought to be $C^k$ if its Fourier coefficients decay like $|n|^{-k}$. This is not quite accurate, but one can use this to define the [Sobolev spaces](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Sobolev_space)
on the circle (more generally on the torus, or using the Fourier transform on euclidean space, and by an extension process on compact manifolds) that describe how many "weak" derivatives a function has. This sort of argument shows that $L^2$ differentiability is roughly comparable with normal differentiability, and using such Sobolev spaces turns out to be integral when one tries to prove explicit bounds about things such as [elliptic regularity](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Elliptic_regularity). There, working with Fourier coefficients (or transforms) and a multiplication operator is significantly easier than working in the original function space with the correspondingly more complicated differential operator. (I am using the fact that constant-coefficient differential operators correspond under the Fourier transform to multiplication by a polynomial.)

Comment: Sorry for bringing up this old topic again, but I just came across this question and answer. If you have the time, could you elaborate a little on how the relationship between degree of differentiability and decay of Fourier coefficients is "not quite accurate"?

Comment: Do you have a reference for the characterization of smooth and Sobolev functions by the Fourier transform for compact manifolds?