# Identification of points of discontinuity of a function

Tags: real-analysis

I had this question in my mind for a long time but I was not sure if it makes sense to anyone.I would appreciate your valuable thoughts on this question.

1. How to identify points of discontinuity of a function $f :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given  samples of the function (obtained by using [Nyquist sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) or any other sampling technique with sampling frequency being as high as desired.)
2. Is there any other alternate way of identifying points of discontinuity without evaluating the limit ?

EDIT 1: functions with a discontinuity are not strictly band-limited. But if we still go ahead by neglecting frequencies higher than certain limit, meaning bandlimiting, we observe the [Gibb's phenomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon).

Comment: There is a close relationship between the degree of differentiability of a function and how quickly its Fourier coefficients decay at infinity; see [this previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10848/does-rapid-decay-of-fourier-coefficients-imply-smoothness). However, since a sampled function throws away information about the Fourier coefficients at higher frequencies, this does not help for your question.

Comment: @Rahul Narain : the second part of the question is not really about sampled function but the actual function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No sampling method that leaves the samples greater than a certain distance apart can identify points of discontinuity unless you are given more information about the function.  The simplest example is the step function:

$H(x) = \begin{cases} 0 \text{  if } x \le 0 \\ 1 \text{  if } x \gt 0 \end {cases}$

Unless you have samples approaching $x=0$ from above arbitrarily closely, you won't be able to tell this from a ramp

$s(x) = \begin{cases} 0 \text{  if } x \le 0 \\ 1/\delta \text {  if } 0 \lt x \le \delta \\ 1 \text{  if } x \gt \delta \end {cases}$

as long as $\delta$ is less than your lowest positive sample point.  If you know your function has no frequencies higher than a certain limit, you can rule it out.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Please comment on the part 2 of the question.

Comment: All I can say on point 2, assuming you are talking about a sampled function, is that seeing the samples of the step function (or something like it) you would suspect a discontinuity.  But absent knowledge of the underlying function, you can't prove it, even at some lower derivative level.  There are $C^{\infty}$ functions that look just like the step as long as  you don't sample in the interval $0 \lt x \le \delta$

Comment: functions with a discontinuity are not strictly bandlimited.

Comment: I am not cosidering the sampled function but the actual function in the second part of the question.

Comment: You are right.  The ramp I defined will also have arbitrarily high frequency components unless you round off the corners.  So if you know your function is bandlimited, you know it is continuous-one result of the Nyquist theorem.