# General Fourier coefficients and smoothness

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, fourier-series

Suppose $f\in L^2([0,1],\lambda)$. Are there assumptions on the smoothness of $f$ which translate into the particular behavior of Frourier coefficients. Namely, I have arbitrary complete orthonormal basis $(\varphi_j)_{j=1}^\infty$ (not necessary trigonometric) and so $$f = \sum_{j=1}^\infty\langle \varphi_j,f\rangle \varphi_j$$

I would like to asses the order of
$$\left\|\sum_{j=m}^\infty \langle \varphi_j,f\rangle \varphi_j\right\|^2 = \sum_{j=m}^\infty|\langle \varphi_j,f\rangle|^2$$

Is it possible to assume that $f$ is smooth in some sense e.g. Holder, or Sobolev with some exponent, which would give me, for instance, $$\sum_{j=m}^\infty|\langle \varphi_j,f\rangle|^2 = O(m^{-\gamma})$$

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10848/does-rapid-decay-of-fourier-coefficients-imply-smoothness (possible duplicate)

Comment: Thomas, I saw this question. What I would like to know is 1. Does this hold for any orthonormal basis (e.g. Legendre polynomials, etc.), 2. What is the formal argument for this (a reference would be nice).

Comment: 3. What kind of smoothness assumption on $f$ translates into the fact that sequence of Fourier coefficients is decreasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is selfadjoint with a complete orthonormal basis of eigenvectors $\{ e_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and corresponding eigenvalues $\{ \lambda_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ that tend to $\infty$ in absolute value. Then
$$
       f \in \mathcal{D}(A^{N}) \iff \sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_{n}^{2N}|(f,e_{n})|^{2} < \infty.
$$
The behavior of the ordinary Fourier coeffficients of $f$ has to do with how many derivatives the function $f$ has, because the functions $\{ e^{2\pi in\theta}\}_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}$ are the eigenfunctions of $\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{d\theta}$ with corresponding integer eigenvalues. The more times you can apply the differentiation operator, the better behaved the Fourier coefficients must be. For example, $f \in L^{2}$ is absolutely continuous and periodic on $[0,1]$ with derivative $f'\in L^{2}$ *if and only if*
$$
                        \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left|\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(\theta)e^{-in\theta}d\theta\right|^{2}n^{2} < \infty.
$$
If you start with an arbitrary set of orthogonal functions $\{ e_{n} \}$ and arbitrarily assigned eigenvalues $\{ \lambda_{n} \}$, then you can define
$$
                       Af = \sum_{n}\lambda_{n}(f,e_{n})e_{n}
$$
Then you definitely get
$$
       f\in\mathcal{D}(A^{N}) \iff \sum_{n}|\lambda_{n}|^{2N}|(f,e_{n})|^{2} < \infty,
$$
but the statement is not of much general use without knowing more about $A$.

The normalized ordinary Legendre polynomials $P_{n}$ are eigenfunctions of the Legendre operator:
$$
                   Lf = -\frac{d}{dx}(1-x^{2})\frac{df}{dx},\\
                       LP_{n} = n(n+1)P_{n},\;\;\; n=0,1,2,\cdots.
$$
The domain of this operator $L$ consists of all bounded twice absolutely continuous functions $f \in L^{2}[-1,1]$ for which $Lf \in L^{2}$. So you can work out what it means for $f \in \mathcal{D}(L^{N})$ in terms of differentiability, but the conditions so required are equivalent to the condition that
$$
      \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n(n+1))^{2N}|(f,P_{n})|^{2} < \infty.
$$
(It is critical that $P_{n}$ be normalized so that $(P_{n},P_{n})=1$.) So, the general rule here is also that "the smoother the $f$, the faster the rate of decay of the Legendre Fourier coefficients $(f,P_{n})$." But this is all just related to the fact that
$$
                         L^{N}f = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\{n(n+1)\}^{N}(f,P_{n})P_{n}.
$$